# .htaccess configuration for thebuggenie

Tags: wordpress, apache

I am a beginner in apache configuration. I am trying to install thebuggenie that runs on apache. I have successfully installed thebuggenie on ubuntu 11, but when I launch it, I get display issues (no css only html) and other login issue. I suppose that it due to incorrect .htaccess configuration. Please help point me in the right direction OR a possible solution.

My setup is

- /var/www/wordpress - http :// mylocalhost/wordpress - Works
- /var/www/thebuggenie-3.1.8/thebuggenie - Does not Work

Location of .htaccess files
 - /var/www/wordpress/.htaccess
 - /var/www/thebuggenie-3.1.8/thebuggenie/.htaccess

/etc/apache2/apache.conf contains

```
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to look at the bug genie configuration. It seems thats CSS / IMAGES/ or JS files do not use the good base path.